# while updating document with mongoose, adds _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongoose, methods

I was trying to make practise with mongoose model-methods. I was trying to update some part of my document with the method `findByIdAndUpdate` and it works actually, but creates some extra `_id` which I dont want to see it.

**here it from server.js:**

```
 app.use("/update", updateRoute);
```

**here ist from the updateRoute**

```
router.patch("/grades/:id", searchGradeAndUpdate);
```

**from controller**

```
exports.searchGradeAndUpdate = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await Restaurant.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { grades: req.body.grades }, { new: true }).lean()
    res.status(200).json({ msg: "restaurant found! SUCCESS!!!", result })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ msg: "restaurant NOT found!! FAIL!!!" })
  }
};
```

**here is the schema and model**

```
    const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const restaurantSchema = new Schema({
  address: {
    building: String,
    coord: [Number],
    street: String,
    zipcode: String
  },
  borough: String,
  cuisine: String,
  grades: [
    {
      date: { type: String, default: new Date() },
      grade: String,
      score: Number
    }
  ],
  name: String,
  restaurant_id: String
})

exports.Restaurant = model("restaurant", restaurantSchema);
```

**that's my URL and JSON as a body**

```
http://localhost:3001/update/grades/5eb3d668b31de5d588f4292a

{"grades": [
            {
                
                "grade": "f",
                "score": 52
            },
            {
                
                "grade": "A",
                "score": 100
            }
        ]
}
```

**here is the result**

```
{
    "msg": "restaurant found! SUCCESS!!!",
    "result": {
        "_id": "5eb3d668b31de5d588f4292a",
        "address": "berlin",
        "borough": "spandau",
        "cuisine": "Anatolian",
        "grades": [
            {
                "date": "Wed Feb 09 2022 14:29:44 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
                "_id": "6203c2e9fbf39efe8e5cf00b",
                "grade": "f",
                "score": 52
            },
            {
                "date": "Wed Feb 09 2022 14:29:44 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
                "_id": "6203c2e9fbf39efe8e5cf00c",
                "grade": "A",
                "score": 100
            }
        ],
        "name": "Ramazan's Kitchen ",
        "restaurant_id": "40356018"
    }
}
```

I dont want the get the `_id` key inside of the array of objects. I wanted them to be like

```
...
"grades": [
            {
                "date": "Wed Feb 09 2022 14:29:44 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
                "grade": "f",
                "score": 52
            },
            {
                "date": "Wed Feb 09 2022 14:29:44 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
                "grade": "A",
                "score": 100
            }
        ]
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to delete them from your query response only use `.select` in your query like so:

```
    const result = await Restaurant.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {grades:req.body.grades }, { new: true }).select('-grades._id').lean()
```

this will make the result exclude all _id properties from the elements of your array.
if you want to delete _id from your elements completely you can define your schema like so:

```
  subschema =  mongoose.Schema({
      date: { type: String, default: new Date() },
      grade: String,
      score: Number
  }, { _id : false });
  const restaurantSchema = new Schema({
    address: {
      building: String,
      coord: [Number],
      street: String,
      zipcode: String
    },
    borough: String,
    cuisine: String,
    grades: [subschema],
    name: String,
    restaurant_id: String
  })
```